# mysqlでGROUP BYした際に同じカラム名の値も表示したい

Tags: mysql, sql

下記のようなテーブルとレコードがあります。

id | user_id | amount | type
1 | 1 | 100 | a
2 | 1 | 200 | b
3 | 1 | 300 | c
4 | 2 | 1000 | a
5 | 2 | 1500 | b
6 | 2 | 2000 | c

これを下記のように取得したいのですがmysqlで可能でしょうか？

user_id | a | b | c
1 | 100 | 200 | 300
2 | 1000 | 1500 | 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あらかじめ `type` の取りうる値がわかっており、`user_id, type` で一意になるなら
次のクエリで取得できます。 (テーブル名は `user_amount`)

```
SELECT `user_id`
, sum(CASE `type` WHEN 'a' THEN `amount` END) `a`
, sum(CASE `type` WHEN 'b' THEN `amount` END) `b`
, sum(CASE `type` WHEN 'c' THEN `amount` END) `c`
FROM `user_amount`
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `user_id`
```

Comment: 遅くなりまして申し訳ございません。なるほど、ありがとうございます！

Comment: @leznupar999 回答にふさわしければ、承認済みにしていただけると助かります。でなければ、ボットによって定期的に質問リストに戻ってきてしまいます。